# Split python list in filtered list of multiple list and store them in single list

Tags: python, django, list, for-loop

I have an exhaustive list of different categories with me:

```
myList = [
   {'name': 'Sasha', 'category': 'Dog'}, 
   {'name': 'Meow', 'category': 'Cat'}, 
   {'name': 'Bark', 'category': 'Dog'}
]
```

I want them to break and a create smaller list within this bigList. It would be similar to this:

```
bigList = [
   [
     {'category': 'Dog', 'name': 'Sasha'}, 
     {'category': 'Dog', 'name': 'Bark'}
   ], 
   [
     {'category': 'Cat', 'name': 'Meow'}
   ]
]
```

Here is the python logic for iterating the loop:

```
bigList = []
prev = ''

for s in myList:
         newList = []
         if s['category'] != prev:
             for m in myList:
                 if m['category'] == s['category']:
                     newList.append(m)
             bigList.append(newList)
        prev = s['category']
```

This has done the trick for me but I would like to know how can I optimize the above logic in for loop for more shorter and efficient code.

Comment: Probably would better fit the [CodeReview site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Will do that quickly.

Comment: Have a look at `itertools`, specifically [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting can be expensive for large lists.

Starting with your data:

```
my_list = [
   {'name': 'Sasha', 'category': 'Dog'}, 
   {'name': 'Meow', 'category': 'Cat'}, 
   {'name': 'Bark', 'category': 'Dog'}
]
```

This loops through all elements of your list once and rembers what its has already seen before in a dictionary:

```
res = []
seen = {}
for entry in my_list:
    val = seen.setdefault(entry['category'], [])
    if not val:
        res.append(val)
    val.append(entry)
```

It appends a new list only for not yet seen entries to `res` but all entries to the corresponding nested list `val` that it got from the `seen` dictionary. So, the same `val` is in `res` and in `seen`. Hence, appending to `val` will enlarge `val` and the effect can be seen no matter if your access `val` through `res` and or `seen`. The line `val = seen.setdefault(entry['category'], [])` gives you either an existing list, if the category was seen before or, a new empty list if the category was encountered the first time. At the same time, if the category is not yet in `seen`, it adds a new key with an empty list as value to `seen`.

This is the result:

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(res)

[[{'category': 'Dog', 'name': 'Sasha'}, {'category': 'Dog', 'name': 'Bark'}],
 [{'category': 'Cat', 'name': 'Meow'}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two steps with `groupby` as commented by @roganjosh:

```
from itertools import groupby

# step 1: sort the list by category, we need this step because groupby only groups same
# adjacent values so we need to sort the list so that same category are close to each other
sort_list = sorted(myList, key = lambda x: x["category"])

# step 2: group by the category and create a new sub list for each group
[list(g) for _, g in groupby(sort_list, key = lambda x: x['category'])]


#[[{'category': 'Cat', 'name': 'Meow'}],
# [{'category': 'Dog', 'name': 'Sasha'}, {'category': 'Dog', 'name': 'Bark'}]]
```